# Jquery Range Slider - Display String Text based on input value - Javascript Array not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, arrays

I'm trying to create a range slider that visually displays different print banner sizes. I have an array set up to display the banner image based on the input value. This works great.

The step i'm stuck on is when i try to display a string of text based on the input value inside the #sliderPrice. As soon as i try to create a second array the code breaks. (I have it commented out in my codepen)

Does anybody know what i'm doing wrong, and how i could achieve the goal of displaying the string inside the sliderPrice div? Ideally i would be able to then style the string using CSS, and position it.

https://codepen.io/stinkytofu3311/pen/ybBpYL?editors=1010

```
var sizeRange = new Array(); 

      size[0] = "11x17 - Starting Price <span>$19.99</span>";

      size[1] = "24x36 - Starting Price <span>$29.99</span>";

      size[2] = "70x90 - Starting Price <span>$39.99</span>";

      size[3] = "120x50 - Starting Price <span>$49.99</span>";

      size[4] = "67x18 - Starting Price <span>$59.99</span>";

      size[5] = "19x30 - Starting Price <span>$69.99</span>";

$(document).on('input change', '#range-slider', function() { //Listen to slider changes (input changes)
    var v=$(this).val(); //Create a Variable (v), and store the value of the input change (Ex. Image 2 [imageURL])

   $('#sliderStatus').html( $(this).val() );
   $('#sliderPrice').html( $(this).val() );

  $("#img").prop("src", imageUrl[v]); // Modify the Images attribute src based on the sliders value, and input the value inside the imageURL[v] to display image
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close to solving it I believe. I updated your array and set sliderPrice = sizeRange[v]. I also set the initial value to sizeRange[0].

[CodePen Link](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GmKywL)

```
var sizeRange = ["11x17 - Starting Price <span>$19.99</span>",
        "24x36 - Starting Price <span>$29.99</span>",
        "70x90 - Starting Price <span>$39.99</span>",
        "120x50 - Starting Price <span>$49.99</span>",
        "67x18 - Starting Price <span>$59.99</span>",
        "19x30 - Starting Price <span>$69.99</span>"]

$('#sliderPrice').html( sizeRange[0] );

$(document).on('input change', '#range-slider', function() { 
   var v=$(this).val();

   $('#sliderStatus').html( $(this).val() );
   $('#sliderPrice').html( sizeRange[v] );

   $("#img").prop("src", imageUrl[v]);
});
```

Comment: That's great. I'm new to JS so that helps a bunch. Did i have the syntax set up incorrectly? I thought i could set up the arrays the same.

Comment: You can keep your old format, but IMO it's a bit overkill unless you want more visibility of what each value represents. The problem with your old format was that you were setting "size", not "sizeRange". If you change them to sizeRange, they will work the same as my format.